# Question about Docusign Integration with Dynamics 365 in relation to the 'Global Admin' user permission

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi, microsoft-dynamics, power-platform

Looking at the [guide to install DocuSign for Dynamics](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=yha1628288295010&topicId=dvk1574179737378.html&_LANG=enus), one of the key items mentioned is:

"Due to CRM and Office 365 API requirements, the user you use to configure the DocuSign integration with Dynamics must be a Global Administrator in the top-level business unit with System Administrator permissions within the Dynamics tenant. This will ensure that all functionality works as designed and is supported by DocuSign."

So I am looking to install Docusign for a customer, but my user does not have 'Global Admin' permissions, just System User.

My question is, if I were to get a Global Admin user or have the permissions assigned to my user and install Docusign, what are the answer to the following scenarios:

1. If my user was given Global Admin permissions, installed Docusign, then those permissions were revoked, would this affect Docusign?
2. If I were to get a Global Admin user to install Docusign, can I configure the settings within dynamics using my System User account without issue?

Answer (score 1):

> If my user was given Global Admin permissions, installed Docusign,
> then those permissions were revoked, would this affect Docusign?

Potentially it could affect as Global Admin privilege could be required for further configurations/changes. Preferred way is ask the customer Global Admin to make the installation.

> If I were to get a Global Admin user to install Docusign, can I
> configure the settings within dynamics using my System User account
> without issue?

Ideally yes, most of the products behave that way for example initial setup Teams installation (Deep integration) require global administrator but further configurations can be done by system administrator as it involves only Dataverse.